# Show information based on what button that was pressed

Tags: java, android

I'm making a information app for Android and I can't figure out how to change a button depending on which button was pressed in a previous class.

I made this picture that shows how the app works:

[image: Flowchart]

After clicking the first button you get to a new class with 2 new buttons that sends you to the same class but the 3 buttons there is supposed to change depending on which one of the two buttons you pressed, the three buttons you get sent to sends you to the same class but there is a TextView that changes text depending on what button you pressed.

So I need to add some kind of information to the button (an intent?) so it knows what you pressed earlier.

I'm kinda new to Java and Android so I'm sorry if I explained in a weird way.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! If you find a response is helpful, please up vote it. If the response successfully answers your question, please click the green check mark next to it to accept the answer. Also please look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask for advice on how to write a good question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each time you start a new Activity, but some extras in that intent telling the next activity what the buttons should display. In the next activity, read the extras from the intent you got, and programatically set your buttons' text accordingly.

Here's some psuedo code.

```
public class FirstActivity extends Activity{

   //setup button 1 and two first, then set their onClickLiseners like so

   View.OnClickListener clickListener = new View.OnClickListener(){
      public void onClick(View view){
        Intent newActivity = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
        if(view == button1){
          //add extra to intent indicating button1 was clicked
        }
        else{
          //add extra to intent indicating button2 was clicked
        }
        startActivity(newActivity);
      }
    };


  // other stuff in your activity
}


public class SecondActivity extends Activity{

  protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle){
     Intent startedBy = getIntent();
     if(started by has the extra indicating button 1 was clicked){
       //do button1 stuff
     }
     else{
       //do button2 stuff 
     }
   }
}


}
```